# Existence of a function with 2 non-divisible periods.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Before I begin I'd like to note that the question deals strictly with one-dimensional real functions. The question is:

Does there exist a periodic function with only 2 periods, where the bigger period is not a whole multiple of the smaller period? On the most basic intuitive level, It doesn't seem possible, but I couldn't find a way to prove it.

Also, if the answer is no, is the following statement (which came up from intuition but again, I couldn't prove) correct?:

"Let $f$ be a periodic function with 2 distinct periods $p_1,p_2$ such that $p_1\neq n\times p_2$, $p_2\neq n\times p_1$ for any natural number $n$. Then there exists a third period of the function $p_3\leq p_1,p_2$ such that $p_1= n\times p_3$, $p_2= m\times p_3$ for some natural numbers $n,m$"

Thanks in advance to all the helpers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange; can you show if $p_1$ and $p_2$ are periods for $f$ then so is $ap_1+bp_2$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb N$ ?

Comment: What is your definition of a period?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven If $p$ is a period of $f$, $f(x)=f(x+p)$ for all $x$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Easily enough. By definition $f(x)=f(x+p_1)$ for all $x$, so $f(x)=f(x+ap_1)$ (Provable by induction) and similarly $f(x)=f(x+bp_2)$. Therefore $f(x+ap_1+bp_2)=f(x+ap_1)=f(x)$, which means $ap_1+bp_2$ is a period of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A periodic $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ cannot have "just two" periods because if $P$ is a period then so is $nP$ for every $n\in \Bbb N.$

(I). Suppose $P_1,P_2$ are positive periods and $P_2/P_1=\frac {a}{b}\ne 1$ where  $a,b\in \Bbb N$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1.$ Then $|mP_1 +nP_2|=|P_1\frac {mb+na}{b}|$ is a period whenever $m,n\in \Bbb Z$ and $mP_1+nP_1\ne 0.$

Now since  $\gcd(a,b)=1$ there exist $u,v\in \Bbb Z$ with $ub+va=1,$ so $P=|uP_1+vP_2|=|P_1\frac {ub+va}{b}|=P_1/b \;$ is a period. And we have $P\le P_1$ and $P\le P_2$ because $P/P_1=1/b$ and $P/P_2=1/a.$

(II). Can a non-constant $f$ have arbitrarily small positive periods? Not if $f$  is continuous. But if $f(x)=0$ when $x\in \Bbb Q$ and $f(x)=1$ when $x \not \in \Bbb Q$ then every $P\in \Bbb Q^+$ is a period ( and no irrational is a period) for $f.$

(III). Can a non-constant $f$ have  periods $P_1,P_2$ such that $P_1/P_2$ is irrational? Yes. Let $S=\{m+n\sqrt 2\,: m,n\in \Bbb Z\}.$ Let $f(x)=0$ if  $x\in S$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\not \in S.$ Then the positive periods of $f$ are the just the positive members of $S,$ so $1$ and  $\sqrt 2\,$ are periods for $f$.

Comment: This answered part of my question, but there is still one thing I'm curious about. Is there any periodic function $f$ with distinct periods $P_1,P_2$ but without another period $P_3$ such that $P_1=nP_3$, $P_2=mP_3$ for some $n,m \in \Bbb N$? You've shown it is not possible if $\frac {P_2} {P_1} \in \Bbb Q$, but is it true in general? or maybe just with continuous functions?

Comment: If $P_2/P_1 \not \in \Bbb Q$ then NO  $P$ can satisfy $P_1=nP$ and $P_2=mP$ with $n,m\in \Bbb N$ because then $P_2/P_1=(mP)/(nP)=m/n\in \Bbb Q.$